# How not to lose component state/scroll position when component is unmounted

Tags: reactjs, react-router

### INTRODUCTION

I have a component which contains 2 child components, let's call them `listComponent` and `itemComponent`.

**listComponent**: has a "load more" button and is scrollable. Each element of the list has a route link which routes to itemComponent.

**itemComponent**: contains the information about a specific element of the list. Has a back button which routes the application back to listComponent.

### THE PROBLEM

Each time the user clicks on an element to go to the itemComponent of that item, it unmounts the listComponent. The problem is that when he goes back the listComponent, it's remounted from scratch, losing all "load more" he did and the scroll position, makind it almost unusable.

### THE QUESTION

I want that when users click the "back" button on itemComponent, listComponent loads as it was when leaved, scrolled where it was and with all the "loaded more" items.

### SAMPLE CODE

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/list"
    component={listComponent}
  />
  <Route
    path="/list/:item"
    component={itemComponent}
  />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Suggestions about a better title for this question are welcome

Comment: why not maintain that state outside of ListComponent? at probably a top-level container which never unmounts? You can start by saving two props viz. the exact ItemComponent selected and the scroll position, on willUnMount of ListComponent. A fiddle would really be helpful in such intricate questions :)